# Options to make Azure Data Factory ETL job work with changing schema of files uploaded by data providers

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

So i have data providers who will upload files using Power Apps, than a ETL job will run and read the content of file and save to DB in cloud. I want a solution in which when the schema of the file changes (column added, removed or changed ) the ETL job will handle it itself.
Is it possible in ADF?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will use ADF Data Flows for this ETL scenario. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-schema-drift